# Appending a List with instances from another class using a For loop

Tags: python

In Python 3, How do I append the first name of instance emp_1 and emp_2 in the class Employee to the self.first list in the class Department using a for loop. Currently I'm appending the list manually for each instance. This would be impractical for many instances.

```
  class Employee:

  def __init__(self,first, last):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
  
  def __iter__(self):
   yield from self.first

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first} {self.last}'


emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Smith')
emp_2 = Employee('Bob', 'Jackson')


class Department:

  def __init__(self):
      self.first = []
      self.last = []

  def __iter__(self):
    yield from self.first
    yield from self.last

  def add_firstname(self,fname):
    self.first.append(fname)

  def add_lastname(self,lname):
    self.last.append(lname)


my_department = Department()

#I would rather use a for loop here

my_department.add_firstname(emp_1.first)
my_department.add_firstname(emp_2.first)

my_department.add_lastname(emp_1.last)
my_department.add_lastname(emp_2.last)

for name in my_department.first:
  print(name)

for name in my_department.last:
  print(name)
```

Comment: How would you do it if it were any other kind of data? Can you write code that handles a single instance of the class? What happened when you put that code inside of a loop? What happened when you tried putting the `Employee` instances in a list in the first place, rather than in separate variables? Did that give you an idea of how to approach the problem?

Comment: Why is `Department` storing two separate lists of first and last names, rather than a single list of `Employee` instances? At the very least, define a single `add_employee` method that takes an instance of `Employee` and uses the public interface of `Employee` to extract the first and last names.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your questions, I'm not familiar with public interface yet.

Comment: @chepner Department is storing 2 separate list so that I can iterate through them independently.

Comment: When would you ever need all the first names, followed by all the last names, in an instance of `Department`?

Answer (score 0):

You can put objects in a list

```
class Employee:
    
      def __init__(self,first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
      
      def __iter__(self):
       yield from self.first
    
      def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}'
    
    employees = [Employee('Corey', 'Smith'),Employee('Bob', 'Jackson')] #you can store objects in a list
    
    class Department:
    
      def __init__(self):
          self.first = []
          self.last = []
    
      def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.first
        yield from self.last
    
      def add_firstname(self,fname):
        self.first.append(fname)
    
      def add_lastname(self,lname):
        self.last.append(lname)
    
    
    my_department = Department()
    
    #I would rather use a for loop here
    for x in employees:
        my_department.add_firstname(x.first)
        my_department.add_lastname(x.last)
    
    
    for name in my_department.first:
      print(name)
    
    for name in my_department.last:
      print(name)
```